# can't retrieve data with jQuery AJAX on button click on .aspx

Tags: javascript

I have this .aspx website with jQuery AJAX.

When I don't have a button, it works fine.

When I wrap AJAX call with a button, it doesn't work. There is no error, no success alert, no AJAX request, nothing in the console. It just stops. I don't know why :(

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#comments').html(data);
                        console.log("success");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <button id="button1">get recent comments</button>

        <div id="comments" runat="server">

        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the button is going to submit the form and post it. You'll want to prevent this behavior in jQuery with `preventDefault()`:

```
$("#button1").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ... etc ...
});
```

Preventing the default behavior of the click event passed by jQuery into your function should make it behave as expected.

---

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I imagine more than the button is being duplicated. It looks as though you might be loading the whole page into itself again? The response you'll want from the form submission would just be a list of the comments that you can drop into your `<ul>`.

Comment: jQuery has a lovely method, `load()`, that might really meet your needs. http://api.jquery.com/load/